# Calculate ROA in PowerBI or Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a question about doing a calculation in my database. This calculation can be either in python (since I built the whole base on it) or in powerbi.

I need to create the ROA using commission with NET for each customer.
The calculation I used in excel was the sum of the comission of the last months (12 months) divided by the NET in the month I want the ROA. I am unable to do this calculation in either python or powerbi. Could you please help me?

(note: my net does not vary much, because it is the customer's custody. So I sum the commission from the last 12 months and divide by the net for the month I am wanting the ROA..)

```
Date    Customer    Net Comission   ROA
jan/21  A   577 9,21    
fev/21  A   725 9,21    
mar/21  A   53  9,21    
abr/21  A   749 9,21    
mai/21  A   886 9,21    
jun/21  A   956 9,21    
jul/21  A   936 9,21    
ago/21  A   424 9,21    
set/21  A   982 9,21    
out/21  A   37  9,21    
nov/21  A   652 9,21    
dez/21  A   39  9,21    
jan/21  B   219 9,21    
fev/21  B   206 9,21    
mar/21  B   848 9,21    
abr/21  B   480 9,21    
mai/21  B   697 9,21    
jun/21  B   118 9,21    
jul/21  B   84  9,21    
ago/21  B   24  9,21    
set/21  B   889 9,21    
out/21  B   91  9,21    
nov/21  B   910 9,21    
dez/21  B   700 9,21
```

Comment: Please, replace your image by the data as plain text.

Comment: what is the difference between these tables?

Comment: @RF1991 table is the same. Just paste as plain text

Answer (score 0):

table

| Date | Customer | Net | Commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | A | 11 | 0,2 |
| 2/1/2021 | A | 265 | 3,7 |
| 3/1/2021 | A | 250 | 3,8 |
| 4/1/2021 | A | 6 | 0,3 |
| 5/1/2021 | A | 320 | 4,2 |
| 6/1/2021 | A | 172 | 2,7 |
| 7/1/2021 | A | 508 | 16,8 |
| 8/1/2021 | A | 625 | 28,2 |
| 9/1/2021 | A | 383 | 17,4 |
| 10/1/2021 | A | 112 | 5,2 |
| 11/1/2021 | A | 81 | 1,3 |
| 12/1/2021 | A | 872 | 19,8 |
| 1/1/2022 | B | 483 | 18,6 |
| 2/1/2022 | B | 389 | 5,5 |
| 3/1/2022 | B | 890 | 52,0 |
| 4/1/2022 | B | 233 | 2,9 |
| 5/1/2022 | B | 293 | 3,6 |
| 6/1/2022 | B | 461 | 21,4 |
| 7/1/2022 | B | 572 | 99,1 |
| 8/1/2022 | B | 106 | 2,4 |
| 9/1/2022 | B | 777 | 13,8 |
| 10/1/2022 | B | 656 | 140,4 |
| 11/1/2022 | B | 268 | 6,8 |
| 12/1/2022 | B | 669 | 8,0 |

you should add a **Calculated Columns** name year in order to produce Year column with following formula:

```
Year = Year('Table'[Date ])
```

use the following **measure** based on description about calculating ROA

```
ROA2 = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Commission]),ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Customer ],'Table'[Year]))/SUM('Table'[Net ])
```

Comment: this formula will help a little bit, I guess. But I want to do the sum in 12 months and I have more than 12 months. Is it possible to do moving sum in this period?

Comment: I have changed my answer that supports the years